# How to select 3 columns and get data from MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select 3 columns and want to retrieve data from the MySQL table. All the columns exist on a single table called `orderTable`.  Please check what I am doing:

```
SELECT * FROM `orderTable` WHERE shipped = 0, reject_order = 0 AND customer_id = '26898'
```

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Replace the * with the columns you want to select

Comment: remove the single quotes arround the ID value. I is not needed for numeric columns

Comment: Where is your attempt to actually get the desired values?  Where is your PHP code?

Comment: You have tagged Laravel. Are you using the Eloquent ORM? Also you have a SQL syntax error: Remove ',' and replace with ' AND '

Comment: SELECT shipped=0,reject_order=0,customer_id ='26898' FROM `orderTable ` WHERE 1 by doing this I am getting a table with 0,1,0,1  an unexpedted result. Not working

Comment: Remember that MySQL is not some mystical force that can only be controlled by those with secret knowledge, it's a well defined program that has [extensive documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) on how you can use it. When you're not sure how to do something, check the manual first, it usually explains or gives hints.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a comma instead of AND or OR condition. See the right query

```
SELECT * FROM `orderTable` WHERE shipped = 0 AND reject_order = 0 AND customer_id = '26898'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `orderTable` WHERE shipped = 0 OR reject_order = 0 AND customer_id = '26898'
```

You should choose one of above based on your requirement